# How to view outputs in a terminal window of a Python application launched at start-up?

Tags: python, boot

I've created a python program that is launched at start-up. To launch it at start-up I've appended a row to the file /etc/rc.local as follow:

```
sudo python3 /home/pi/myProgram.py
```

Every some seconds, Myprogram.py prints a debug message.
When I turn on my Raspberry, I cannot view myProgram.py to run. I'm sure that it works fine because when the program starts it sends me an e-mail but I cannot view the terminal window where myProgram.py prints the debug messages.
Question: How can I view output of myProgram.py in a terminal window?

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
python3 /home/pi/myProgram.py 2>&1 | logger -t my-program
```

That way all output will end up in the system log in /var/log/syslog

Comment: One of the first things I do on a new Pi is disable all logging to the SD card (in an attempt to improve SD card lifetime) so it would not work for me.  I'd certainly do this on a hard drive based machine.

Comment: You're right. That's probably a good idea on the PI with the default syslog setup. On a custom distribution I built I'm using busybox's syslogd which has the ability to log to a circular memory buffer. So it's not a problem in that case.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to use sudo for programs started in /etc/rc.local, they are run as root.

I suggest you redirect stdout to a file, e.g.

`python3 /home/pi/myProgram.py >/tmp/mydebugfile`

If possible replace /tmp (or whatever you choose) with a file system stored in RAM or on the nextwork to minimise SD card read/writes.

Then to view your debug messages use

`tail /tmp/mydebugfile`